# как сохранить значение textarea - и чтобы на сайте показало пробелы и новые строки

Tags: php, html

как сохранить значение textarea - и чтобы на сайте показало пробелы и новые строки

Comment: сохранить можно в файл или в БД, а для визуального форматирования можно использовать `nl2br()`

Comment: Спосибо вы мне помагли очень!